# How to whitelist READ_PHONE_STATE permission (Privilaged Permissions)?

Tags: java, android

Android 10 changes the permissions **F**or device identifiers so that all device identifiers are now protected by the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission. and I cannot find a way to **U**se READ_PHONE_STATE permission to get all those identifiers (e.g IMEI, IMSI and Build serial) using TelephonyManager.

I tried `getImei()` and `getDeviceId()` but I am still getting Null when I **C**all them all. I **K**now there should be a way to whitelist my app or permission but I don't know how!!!

```java
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getImei(0);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That permissions is not available for 3rd party apps installed via the Play store.  Only OEM apps which are bundled with the platform can have that permission.  This is outlined in the Android 10 notes:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/device-identifiers#device-identifiers-implementation

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist

what are these links talking about?

Comment: They are talking about exactly what I just said: apps which are bundled with the platform itself.  These are app packages that the OEM, chipset vendor, or carrier can bundle into the device.  They are not something which a 3rd party developer can use.

Comment: so there is no alternative for getting those identifiers as a 3rd party developer you say?

Comment: Correct.  With Android 10 you cannot access these any longer as a 3rd party dev.